# Master Template name is being reset after reopening application

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I cloned a project on Sourcetree and created `.ntf`s using the given `on disc project` that I imported. These `.ntf`s had no master template declared so I tried to declare them manually.

When I close and reopen the template, the master template name is either reset or gone completely.

If I do the whole process on a local project, I can freely rename the master template with no problems whatsoever.

I have full access administration permissions and am working on a domino server on my local virtual box VM.

I created a new `.ntf` using the existing one and encountered the same problem.

Furthermore, there is no difference in changing the name in the Domino Designer or Domino Administrator client.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Domino that does this "security" Check: Whenever you try to create an .ntf on a server with a template name (Database properties, Design- Tab, Database is master template) that does already exist on the server then the template name and the database title are reset to blank.

This is done to prohibit two templates with the same template name on the server as the results would be unpredictable. You need to clean the template name or reset title and template name in a second step. I usually either create the copy on local and change the template name before I replicate it to the server or I use code to create the copy and set template name and database title after creating the database with NotesDatabase.Title = and an API- Class to set the TemplateName Property.

Answer (score 2):

There's a specific field on the Security tab of the server document that specifies the IDs with this authority, "Create master templates". Make sure your ID is in this field.